# Moving a bone in multiple keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

So i have blender 2.83.3.
In my scene I have 600+ keyframes, and there is a bone that I want the move to a different location for 500 of those keyframes.

Is there a fast way to move those or do i have to more them keyframe by keyframe?
I thank anyone with more XP then me!

Comment: have you tried to do it via the Graph Editor? You need to select the bone, enable the Only Show Selected option, select the track you want to change, like X Location, lock the others, select the curve vertices between frame 1 and 500 and move them

Comment: Thank you! i'll try that this evening when i get a moment.

Comment: Yup this is the answer I needed to learn about! Thank you.if you copy this I'll choose it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it via the *Graph Editor*.

You need to select the bone, enable the *Only Show Selected* option (arrow button), select the track you want to change, like *X Location*, lock the others (or hide them with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, select the curve vertices between frame 1 and 500 and move them in the *Graph Editor* Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

enable auto keying , and start , that small record type button next to play button on the left in the timeline